# Every function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is continuous in each variable separately is Borel measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I'm trying to solve exercise 2.11 from Folland's Real Analysis.

[image]

Firstly, how do we show that $f_n$ is Borel measurable on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^k$? I really have no idea how to show this when we have separately Borel measurable functions.

Next, I can't show that $f_n\to f$ pointwise.

For any $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^k$,

$f_n(x,y)=n[f(a_{i+1},y)(x-a_i)-f(a_i,y)(x-a_{i+1})]=n[x[f(a_{i+1},y)-f(a_i,y)]+\frac{1}{n}[f(a_i,y)-f(a_{i+1},y)]]$,

but because of the $n$ outside the bracket, I can't show that this converges to $f$. How can I show this? Also, how can I conclude from this fact that every function on $R^n$ that is continuous in each variable separately is Borel measurable?

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions, hints, or solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if $t=\frac{x-a_i}{a_{i+1}-a_i}$, then  $0\leq t\leq 1$, and $1-t=-\frac{x-a_{i+1}}{a_{i+1}-a_i}$. Hence $f_n(x,y)=tf(a_{i+1},y)+(1-t)f(a_i, y)$. Hence $f_n(x,y)$ is in the interval with endpoints $f(a_i,y)$ and $f(a_{i+1},y)$. As $a_i$ and $a_{i+1}\to x$ as $n\to +\infty$, by the hypothesis we get $f_n(x,y)\to f(x,y)$.

EDIT:

Put $b_i={\rm Min}\{ f(a_i,y), f(a_{i+1},y)\}$ and $b_i={\rm Max}\{ f(a_i,y), f(a_{i+1},y)\}$. By the expression $f_n(x,y)=tf(a_{i+1},y)+(1-t)f(a_i,y)$, we have $b_i\leq f_n(x,y)\leq c_i$. Now, when $n\to \infty$, $b_i$ and $c_i \to f(x,y)$, this show $f_n(x,y)\to f(x,y)$.

To see that $f_n$ is Borel-mesurable, note that $f_n$ is Borel-mesurable on each of the sets $[i/n,(i+1)/n]\times \mathbb{R}^k$

Comment: I can see your reasoning, but I'm not sure about it, can you help me understand? So you're trying to show that $\lim f_n(x,y)=t\lim f(a_{i+1},y)+(1-t)\lim f(a_i,y)=tf(x,y)+(1-t)f(x,y)$, using continuity of $f(\dot,y)$, however, isn't $\lim t=0$? Or at least $t$ is affected by the limit so I don't see how you can separate them. Also, can you help me with showing that $f_n$ is Borel measurable? I thought this was obvious, but seeing it again, I'm not sure how I can show this.

Comment: I have edited my answer, I hope that this can help.

Comment: Sorry but I really don't see why $f_n$ is Borel-measurable on each of the sets you mentioned, and how this shows $f_n$ is Borel measurable on the whole set.

Comment: Although this is many years later, I would like to supplement why $f_n$ Borel measurable for others' reference. To be convenient for writing and reading assume $k=1$. The case $k\ge 2$ is quite similar . Note that in $f_n(x,y)=tf(a_{i+1},y)+(1-t)f(a_i, y),$
the value of $a_l$ is in fact affected by $n$, and $t=\frac{x-a_i}{a_{i+1}\ \ -\ \ a_i}$ is therefore a function of $x, n$. For fixed $i,n$ we rewrite 
$$f_n(x,y)=t(x,i,n)f(a_{n,i+1},y)+(1-t(x,i,n))f(a_{n,\ i}\ , \ y).$$
for $(x,y)\in [\dfrac{i}{n},\dfrac{i+1}{n}]\times\mathbb{R}$.(to be continued)

Comment: (contiunue) This is continuous as a two variable function, and is hence Borel-measurable on its interior $ (\dfrac{i}{n},\dfrac{i+1}{n})\times\mathbb{R}$, and thus Borel-measurable on $\cup_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}(\dfrac{i}{n},\dfrac{i+1}{n})\times\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}^2-\{\frac{i}{n}| i\in\mathbb{Z}\}\times\mathbb{R}$ . (Subtracting a set of measure zero does not matter)